# express server not sending response

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code:

route:

```
router.get('/students', function(req, res,next) {

    studentsApi.getAllStudents(function(err, items) {

        res.json( {student:items});
    })
});
```

api.js:

```
let jsonData= require('./students');

let jsoneData=JSON.parse(jsonData);
let _copy = function(item) {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
};

let studentsApi = {
    getAllStudents: function(callback) {
        callback(null, _copy(jsoneData));
    }
}
module.exports = studentsApi;
```

I am able to see the default express page at `localhost:3000` but `localhost:3000/students` returns *404 error*. students is a js file

Comment: If you get a 404 error, the router isn't mounted properly (using `app.use()`)

Comment: oh..! how careless i was